# Java List in Multi-thread environment

Tags: java, multithreading, list, synchronized

I would like to convert the following code to fit multithread environment.

```java
List<Observer> list = new ArrayList<>();

public void removeObserver(Observer p) {
    for (Observer observer: list) {
        if (observer.equals(p)) {
            list.remove(observer);
            break; 
        }
    }
}

public void addObserver(Observer p) {
    list.add(p);
}

public void notifyObserver(Event obj) {
    for (Observer observer: list) {
        observer.notify(obj);   
    }
}
```

Definitely, one of the easiest way to do so, is to add `synchronized` keyword, which ensure only one thread can runs the logic, and thereby ensuring result is correct.

However, is there better way to solve the issue. I have do some sort of research, and found that I can use `Collections.synchronizedList`, and also notice such `list.iterator is not thread-safe`, so I should avoid use of forEach loop or iterator directly [unless I do a `synchronized (list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-)
I just don't want to use synchronized, and think if there is another possible approach. Here is my second attempt.

```java
List<Observer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Observer>()); // which is thread safe

public void removeObserver(Observer p) {
    // as the list may get modify, I create a copy first
    List<Observer> copy = new CopyOnWriteArrayList(list);
    for (Observer observer: copy) {
        if (observer.equals(p)) {
            // but now, no use of iterator
            list.remove(observer); // remove it from the original copy
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void addObserver(Observer p) {
    list.add(p);
}

public void notifyObserver(Event obj) {
    List<Observer> copy = new CopyOnWriteArrayList(list); 
    // not use iterator, as thread safe list's iterator can be thread unsafe
    // and for-each loop use iterator concept
    for (Observer observer: copy) {
        observer.notify(obj);
    }
}
```

I just want to ask if my second attempt is thread-safe? Also, is there a better approach to do this then my proposed second method?

Comment: You should switch your =='s to `.equals()` especially since the list.remove is going to be using `.equals()` so you might remove a different object than you intend.

Comment: Consider using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` or similar.

Comment: Why not just call `list.remove(p);`, skip the whole create a copy and iterate over its contents.

Comment: List<Observer> copy = new CopyOnWriteArrayList(list) is superfluous in my opinion. The Collections.synchronizedList() does quite well with my own experience. My self-developed Object-Orieted Database works exclusively with Collections.synchronizedList and ConcurrentHashMap and i have no problems with multiple users (or threads)

Answer (score 1):

> Definitely, one of the easiest way to do so, is to add synchronized keyword, which ensure only one thread can runs the logic, and thereby ensuring result is correct.

This is correct.

> However, is there better way to solve the issue?

Possibly.  But lets take look at your second attempt:

```
List<Observer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Observer>()); 
       // which is thread safe
```

Yes it is thread-safe.  With certain constraints.

```
public void removeObserver(Observer p) {
    // as the list may get modify, I create a copy first
    List<Observer> copy = new CopyOnWriteArrayList(list);
    ...
```

Three problems here:

1. You are creating a copy of the list.  That is an `O(N)` operation.
2. The `CopyOnWriteArrayList` constructor is going to iterate `list` ... and iteration of a list created by `synchronizedList` is not atomic / thread-safe so you have a race condition.
3. There is no actual benefit of using `CopyOnWriteArrayList` here over (say) `ArrayList`.  The `copy` object is local and thread-confined so it doesn't need to be thread-safe.

In summary, this is not thread-safe AND it is more expensive simply making the original methods synchronized.

---

A possibly better way:

```
List<Observer> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList()

public void removeObserver(Observer p) {
    list.remove(p)
}

public void addObserver(Observer p) {
    list.add(p);
}

public void notifyObserver(Event obj) {
    for (Observer observer: list) {
        observer.notify(obj);
    }
}
```

This is thread-safe with the caveat that an `Observer` added while a `notifyObserver` call is in progress will not be notified.

The only potential problem is that mutations to a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` are expensive since they create a copy of the entire list.  So if the ratio of mutations to notifies is too high, this may be more expensive than the solution using `synchronized` methods.  On the other hand, if multiple threads call `notifyObserver`, those calls can proceed in parallel.